# How to get the birthday from a windows phone 8.1 (NOT Silverlight) contact

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to populate a listview with all my phone contact's birthdays but unfortunately it seems more difficult than I initially thought - or I am missing something big...

Concerning Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight it seems to be [easy](http://biranchipanda.com/blog/c-snippet-to-get-contacts-from-windows-phone-with-birthday-on-date/) as there is a Birthday property. But how to get the birthday of a contact in Windows Phone 8.1 Runtime?

Why isn't there a property? It could be so easy...

```
var contactStore = await ContactManager.RequestStoreAsync();
var contacts = await contactStore.FindContactsAsync();

foreach (var contact in contacts) 
{   
   // var birthday = contact.Birthday;  // unfortunately not possible 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.contacts.contactdatekind.aspx) here pointed me finally to the right direction:

```
var contactStore = await ContactManager.RequestStoreAsync();
var contacts = await contactStore.FindContactsAsync();

foreach (var contact in contacts) 
{   
   // var list = contact.ImportantDates;
   // Enumerating this list we can check for ContactDateKind == Birthday
   // Or even shorter:

   var birthday = contact.ImportantDates.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Kind == ContactDateKind.Birthday);

   // birthday is null if there is no birthday saved for the current contact
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `Microsoft Live Connect Api`. Go through this link http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Birthday_Calendar_for_Windows_Phone

You can also check How to access calendar data for Windows Phone 8?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh286421%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

### Edit

Try this

```
var store = await ContactStore.CreateOrOpenAsync();
StoredContact sc = new StoredContact(store);
IDictionary<string, object> values = await sc.GetPropertiesAsync();
```

Here you can use `KnownContactProperties.Birthdate`. Might be this will help you.

Comment: Hey Ajay, thanks for adding additional information. But as I don't need calendar nor facebook I can reduce complexity and just use the ImportantDates list.

Comment: You want important dates or birthdate?

Comment: I only want birthdays but with "d.Kind == ContactDateKind.Birthday" I can easily filter these out.

Comment: Thank you for your edit but if I see it correct this will give me the contacts from my custom contact store. I wanted to use the phone contact store. CreateOrOpenAsync: "Opens the app's custom contact store, creating the store with the default options if it does not already exist."